# Windows 10 battery percentage of design or full charge capacity?

Tags: windows-10, battery-life

Is the battery indicator in Windows 10 a percentage of the design capacity or the current full charge capacity of the battery ?

ie. if my battery capacity dropped from say, 60mWh to 30mWh from wear, would the indicator show 50% or 100% when the battery is fully charged at its current capacity of 30mWh ?

EDIT: to describe my case, I have an XPS 13 9350 whose battery has a design capacity of 56mWh. over the past few weeks, the battery percentage in windows stops at 55 with "plugged in not charging". running

```
powercfg \batteryreport
```

shows that the current full charge capacity is about 41mWh, meaning at 55% I'm getting about 20mWh on a "full" charge. the surprising thing is Dell Command Power Manager shows my battery to be in excellent health.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current full charge - to get the design capacity, you have to use some special tools that are OEM specific - like Dell Command Monitor for Dell laptops.

Some management tools will compare the current capacity with the design capacity and give you "battery health" but not Windows

This is why you may see the battery indicator being "full" and when disconnecting external power, the system will immediately hibernate/turn off

Comment: so my percentage should still reach 100 or close to it right ? my xps 13 is right now at 40mWh from 55 mWh, but seems to only reach 50% that is 20mWh.

Comment: What are you using to obtain these values? The Windows indicator shows capacity in % and time, not Wh values

Comment: powercfg report shows me the 55mWh design and 40mWh current capacities. my windows % doesnt seem to go above ~50%, which by your answer means that I'm actually getting only about 20mWh of charge.

Comment: yes, I would replace the battery and verify the embedded charger controller